# Optical mirroring

Tags: 10gbethernet, port-mirroring

I have a 10G XPF+ optical cable with market updates from a stock exchange. This cable goes into a switch, which then mirrors every packet to a couple of computers over two ports. The problem with using a switch for mirroring is that there is latency overhead, even with a pass-through switch (~200ns).

Are there "optical" solutions (I'm thinking of a beam splitter of some sort) which would allow for close to zero latency 10G mirroring?

Comment: You HFAT guys are *so* crazy.

Comment: There is a solution... I know of a couple of devices that would help you bypass the switch. What devices are in use here? Arista?

Comment: @Randomblue I'm under [NDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)... but I'll update as soon as I can speak about it.

Comment: Okay. I can talk about it. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My old firm manufactures a [port replicator](http://low-latency.com/article/xcelor-xpr-device-copies-market-data-two-nanoseconds) that solves the problem you're having. It's a Layer 1 device that can take a market data feed and multiplex to a number of ports at *<10ns* latencies. This bypasses the Arista switch for one-way market data consumption.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there "optical" solutions (I'm thinking of a beam splitter of some
>   sort) which would allow for essentially zero latency 10G multicast?

No.

Comment: Ye' cannae' break the laws of Physics, Jim!

Comment: "beam splitter" effectively splits the photon stream, so only half the photons goes each way. this possibly breaks the signal sent. Amaright ?

Comment: @Randomblue - certainly prismatic optical networking adds VERY little, not zero, but very little latency to the equation - the issue here though is that you still need to turn the data into regular ethernet and there's no real way of doing that without some form of switch involved - which inherently brings latency. Bay Networking used to sell a range called ONS that was designed for just this thing but I think that line got dropped or sold-on when they went bust - perhaps you could look around as I'm sure there are better products to use than 'regular' switches. Good luck.

Comment: @Randomblue I'm not sure I see your point - even light has a finite speed.

Comment: @Randomblue - yes, but you need *a* switch of some form to do that sorry

Comment: That's an error message waiting to happen "Insufficient critical photons detected".

Comment: Randomblue: Ethernet over Fibre is not an analog signal.  It's a digital one...

Comment: @Randomblue I'm very aware of optical network taps, I work for the biggest buyer of them in Europe, they don't provide multicast-like functionality at all, they're more similar to a span port.

Comment: @Chopper3: "I work for the biggest buyer [of optical network taps] in Europe" -> Do you work for GCHQ by any change? Or the NSA?

Comment: @Randomblue If you come into chat, we've started compiling a list of people who've asked Chopper3 direct questions and then disappeared. I'd suggest locking your doors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, port mirroring is possible using network taps, with latency an order of magnitude less than a using a switch. There is a video demonstration [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5aMycCLX_A#t=217).